# cordova - Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzc

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to compile a cordova app for android and I am getting this error. Any ideas?
This is the error I am getting:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForArmv7Debug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzc;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I tried adding --stacktrace --debug at the end but I am getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I also randomly started getting this error this morning _(where it was working perfectly yesterday with the same build of the app)_. The solution for me was to upgrade one of my plugins - **phonegap-plugin-push** - to the latest version 1.10.5. I don't know why this has sorted the problem for me hence why I haven't submitted this as an answer. Side note: this was happening for me when being built by Phonegap Build.

Comment: @BenJ You saved my day!

Comment: @BenJ Any clue what caused the issue? same thing happened to me with phonegap-plugin-push plugin.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This issue is caused by a mismatch of versions of the Google Play Services library specified by two or more plugins.

> The solution for me was to upgrade one of my plugins - phonegap-plugin-push - to the latest version 1.10.5.

This worked because `phonegap-plugin-push@1.10.5` contains [a commit](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/commit/9de2707880b17e0e4039ba05ee5d7b9a435d404b) which changed the pinned version from `10.2+` to `11+`.

Most likely you have another plugin in your project which specifies `com.google.android.gms:*:+`, which will currently also resolve to v11, because this is currently the [latest release](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).

**Update**

Since I've been encountering this problem myself, I've just created a plugin which contains a Gradle workaround for plugins containing conflicting versions of the Play Services library: [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release). You should just be able to add it to your problematic project and it should fix the build:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release
```

Comment: please help me check this problem, thank you very much
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954049/ionic2-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you for your work on that library :)

Answer (score 0):

> The solution is to upgrade phonegap-plugin-push@1.10.5  only.

There is no need to update any other thing.