# ionic2 - Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

**When I `ionic cordova build android --release` error coming**

**ios build success already, but android cannot build for me, first time face this problem, before build fun**

Recently, I add some codova plugin and third party login sdk in my project and now not working for me

```
zhungzhens-MacBook-Air:minan zhungzhenzhungzhen$ ionic cordova build android
Running app-scripts build: --build --iscordovaserve --externalIpRequired --nobrowser

[15:18:50]  build dev started ... 
[15:18:50]  clean started ... 
[15:18:50]  clean finished in 8 ms 
[15:18:50]  copy started ... 
[15:18:50]  transpile started ... 
[15:18:55]  transpile finished in 5.83 s 
[15:18:55]  preprocess started ... 
[15:18:56]  deeplinks started ... 
[15:18:56]  deeplinks finished in 105 ms 
[15:18:56]  preprocess finished in 106 ms 
[15:18:56]  webpack started ... 
[15:18:56]  copy finished in 6.34 s 
[15:19:10]  webpack finished in 14.86 s 
[15:19:10]  sass started ... 
[15:19:12]  sass finished in 1.75 s 
[15:19:12]  postprocess started ... 
[15:19:12]  postprocess finished in 8 ms 
[15:19:12]  lint started ... 
[15:19:12]  build dev finished in 22.64 s 
> cordova build android
⠙ Running command [15:19:22]  lint finished in 10.16 s 
✖ Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

        (truncated) ... rscript UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
        :CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72531Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72531Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2531Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2531Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2531Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2531Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2531Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2531Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42531Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2531Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComCommit451PhotoView124Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4260Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareOpenDefault206Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareOrgApacheCordovaCordovaLib623DebugLibrary
        :prepareDebugDependencies
        :compileDebugAidl
        :compileDebugRenderscript
        :generateDebugBuildConfig
        :generateDebugResValues
        :generateDebugResources
        :mergeDebugResources
        :processDebugManifest/Users/zhungzhenzhungzhen/Desktop/minan/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:54:9-242
        Error:
        Element activity#com.zhungzhen.minanapp.wxapi.WXEntryActivity at AndroidManifest.xml:54:9-242 duplicated with
        element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-27:20
        /Users/zhungzhenzhungzhen/Desktop/minan/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Validation failed, exiting


        See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

        :processDebugManifest FAILED

        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
        > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

        BUILD FAILED

        Total time: 11.711 secs
        Error: /Users/zhungzhenzhungzhen/desktop/minan/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error
        output:
        /Users/zhungzhenzhungzhen/Desktop/minan/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:54:9-242 Error:
        Element activity#com.zhungzhen.minanapp.wxapi.WXEntryActivity at AndroidManifest.xml:54:9-242 duplicated with
        element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-27:20
        /Users/zhungzhenzhungzhen/Desktop/minan/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Validation failed, exiting

        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
        > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

> Two plugins are requesting different versions of the android support
>   library here.

This is what I found from internet, is it plugin problem?

This is my plugin list

```
com-sarriaroman-photoviewer 1.1.10 "PhotoViewer"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-qqsdk 0.9.6 "QQSDK"
cordova-plugin-sharesdk 0.1.0 "ShareSDK"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-wechat 2.0.0 "Wechat"
cordova-plugin-weibosdk 0.6.0 "WeiboSDK"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.8 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

UPDATE!!!

Finally I solved this problem and I wrote the way in the answer.
[image]

Comment: @DaveAlden please come help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, this error is the cordova plugins problem.

For my project is the `weibosdk` plugin problem

I just remove my weibosdk plugin, and found a new latest plugin add in my project, then build success.

> cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-weibosdk

So when you meet this problem, type `ionic cordova plugin list` to list what you add in your project, then check your plugin which out of date or other problem.

If you have other advices, please comment in this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is an issue with the facebook plugin.
https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/507

- For android builds i use the version 1.7.4. (cordova-plugin-facebook4@1.7.4).
- For ios builds i use the version 1.9.1 (cordova-plugin-facebook4@1.9.1).

Between builds, i remove the plugins, platforms and resources and re-generate everything.

Comment: So.. I have to remove all plugins first, then rebuild it?

Comment: Finally I found the way to solve the error, but still thanks for answer my question and upvote for you.