# Ionic Cordova Build failure

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I recently recovered my ionic source code from a crashed PC and tried setting up a new PC, after the installations of the required files. I tried building the project, but got an error as below. I have been trying to figure out where and how to update the `AndroidManifest.xml` to reflect the suggestion in the error message. Any help to resolve this and build my project would be welcome.

**output from the build terminal:'**

> BUILD FAILED
>  Total time: 2 mins 19.549 secs
>  FAILURE: Build
>   failed with an exception.

- What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from
>   [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>           is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>           Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>   or --debug option to get more log output.
>  (node:8808)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error
>   output: Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files
>   use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. C:\wamp64\www\myapp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>   Error:
>           Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>           is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).

Suggestion:

> add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>           is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>   or --debug option to get more log output.

**package.json file**

```
    {
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@ionic-native/app-minimize": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/crop": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-dynamic-links": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/image-resizer": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/native-audio": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/sim": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/sms": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "angular4-paystack": "^2.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "com.synconset.imagepicker": "~2.1.8",
    "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": "^0.6.5",
    "cordova-android": "~6.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-appminimize": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-crop": "^0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm": "^2.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.6.3",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": "^3.0.9",
    "cordova-plugin-sim": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.1.8",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.2.1",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.0.0",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.1.0",
    "firebase": "^4.6.0",
    "info.protonet.imageresizer": "^0.1.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.15",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.2",
    "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "~0.0.2",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-sim": {},
      "com.synconset.imagepicker": {
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "select image"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-crop": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-appminimize": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": {},
      "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "myappapp",
        "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "https",
        "DEEPLINK_HOST": "myappmobile.firebaseapp.com",
        "ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX": "/myapppp",
        "ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_2_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_3_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_4_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_5_HOST": " "
      },
      "info.protonet.imageresizer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm": {},
      "cordova-plugin-compat": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show your package.json?

Comment: Please first check your gradle version :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest 2> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954049/ionic2-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest , 3> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-package-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest/94270 , For ionic 3 :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411610/ionic-3-build-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411610/ionic-3-build-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest solved my problem> Thanks man.

Comment: didn't work for me !! And I have the exact same issue