# IONIC 1 Android Build Error, transformClassesWithDexForRelease

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am facing an error while running

> ionic cordova build android --release

command.
Below is the error

```
transformClassesWithDexForRelease
```

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.uti
  >   l.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gm
  >   s/iid/zzc;
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44593496/777265

Answer (score 1):

Change this file  (..\platforms\android\build.gradle)

```
defaultConfig {


    versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
    applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

    if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
        minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
    }
}
```

to this

```
defaultConfig {

      minSdkVersion 21
   targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true

    versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
    applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

    if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
        minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
    }
}
```